# How to get data HTTP response code 5xx from multiple files with bash script in different directory

Tags: bash

I am learning about bash scripting, but I might need some example for this:
am has 2 or more files, file1 in directory /home/usr/file1 with this data:

```
83.149.9.216 - - [17/May/2015:10:05:07 +0000] "GET /presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/plugin/notes/notes.js HTTP/1.1" 501 2892 "http://semicomplete.com/presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.77 Safari/537.36"
83.149.9.216 - - [17/May/2015:10:05:34 +0000] "GET /presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/images/sad-medic.png HTTP/1.1" 502 430406 "http://semicomplete.com/presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.77 Safari/537.36"
83.149.9.216 - - [17/May/2015:10:05:57 +0000] "GET /presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/css/fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf HTTP/1.1" 500 38720 "http://semicomplete.com/presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.77 Safari/537.36"
```

so also, file2 in directory /home/usr/usr2/file2 with this data:

```
46.105.14.53 - - [17/May/2015:11:05:33 +0000] "GET /blog/tags/puppet?flav=rss20 HTTP/1.1" 500 14872 "-" "UniversalFeedParser/4.2-pre-314-svn +http://feedparser.org/"
5.102.173.71 - - [17/May/2015:11:05:13 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MojeekBot/0.6; http://www.mojeek.com/bot.html)"
5.102.173.71 - - [17/May/2015:11:05:06 +0000] "GET /projects/xdotool/ HTTP/1.1" 200 12292 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MojeekBot/0.6; http://www.mojeek.com/bot.html)"
208.91.156.11 - - [17/May/2015:11:05:05 +0000] "GET /files/logstash/logstash-1.3.2-monolithic.jar HTTP/1.1" 404 324 "-" "Chef Client/10.18.2 (ruby-1.9.3-p327; ohai-6.16.0; x86_64-linux; +http://opscode.com)"
```

well, how to combine/read all data in different directory with bash script. I want output like this to get response 5xx from that file:

```
83.149.9.216 [17/May/2015:10:05:07 +0000 HTTP/1.1" 501
83.149.9.216 [17/May/2015:10:05:34 +0000] HTTP/1.1" 502
46.105.14.53 [17/May/2015:11:05:33 +0000] HTTP/1.1" 500
5.102.173.71 [17/May/2015:11:05:13 +0000] HTTP/1.1" 500
etc...
```

Comment: What do you mean by _combine_? Why can't you read from different directories? You did not post the result you want to achieve, nor did you post what you tried to get at this result.

Comment: edited for the result @user1934428, might any consern or example?

Comment: Since you seem to want alphanumerically according to the IP addresses, I would simply `cat` both files and pipe them into `sort`.

Comment: What is the problem? Where you got stuck?

Comment: well i will try @user1934428

Comment: @ceving need example for create bash script for the result, still go stuck with the logic/process, might any example will be appreciate

Comment: Try this: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-the-bash/0596009658/

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
sort /home/usr/file1  /home/usr/usr2/file2
```

?

Comment: Yeah, but the process need create on file script #!/bin/bash, so need some example with the logic/process

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of the words _process need create on file script_, but from what I see, my suggested answer provides the exact result for the example data you have posted. Hence, if something is still missing, please as a **new** question, defining exactly your requirements. Don't forgot to also post your own attempts to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your question is, but just in case, you do not know how to write the regular expression to parse your web server logs:

```sh
#! /bin/bash

exec <<EOF
83.149.9.216 - - [17/May/2015:10:05:07 +0000] "GET /presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/plugin/notes/notes.js HTTP/1.1" 501 2892 "http://semicomplete.com/presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.77 Safari/537.36"
83.149.9.216 - - [17/May/2015:10:05:34 +0000] "GET /presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/images/sad-medic.png HTTP/1.1" 502 430406 "http://semicomplete.com/presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.77 Safari/537.36"
83.149.9.216 - - [17/May/2015:10:05:57 +0000] "GET /presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/css/fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf HTTP/1.1" 500 38720 "http://semicomplete.com/presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.77 Safari/537.36"
46.105.14.53 - - [17/May/2015:11:05:33 +0000] "GET /blog/tags/puppet?flav=rss20 HTTP/1.1" 500 14872 "-" "UniversalFeedParser/4.2-pre-314-svn +http://feedparser.org/"
5.102.173.71 - - [17/May/2015:11:05:13 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MojeekBot/0.6; http://www.mojeek.com/bot.html)"
5.102.173.71 - - [17/May/2015:11:05:06 +0000] "GET /projects/xdotool/ HTTP/1.1" 200 12292 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MojeekBot/0.6; http://www.mojeek.com/bot.html)"
208.91.156.11 - - [17/May/2015:11:05:05 +0000] "GET /files/logstash/logstash-1.3.2-monolithic.jar HTTP/1.1" 404 324 "-" "Chef Client/10.18.2 (ruby-1.9.3-p327; ohai-6.16.0; x86_64-linux; +http://opscode.com)"
EOF

while read -r line; do
  if [[ $line =~ ^(((^|\.)[0-9]{1,3}){4})\ -\ -(\ \[[^\]]+\])\ \"GET\ [^\"]*\"(\ [0-9]{3}).*$ ]]; then
    for i in 1 4 5; do
      printf %s "${BASH_REMATCH[$i]}"
    done
    printf '\n'
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, after research more. i have the result for the output:

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ] 
do 
    result=`cat "$arg1" "$arg2" | awk '{print $ouput1 " " $ouput2 " "}' |  grep -E "50[0-9]|520"`
    echo "$result"
    exit 1
done
```